# After collapsing Django project's top-most folder, can't find settings module

Tags: python, django

When I initially created my Django project, I had this file folder structure:

```
project/
    project/
        manage.py
        settings.py
        ...
```

In the topmost folder I have my git repo initialized as well as my vitual environment.

I want to collapse the top folder level (as if I had run `django-admin.py startproject .':

```
project/
    manage.py
    settings.py
```

However, when I tried to do this manually, it suddenly can't find the settings module. It's still looking for it at `project.settings.` Where might this be hardcoded?

When I run `python manage.py runserver`, I get this error:

```
ImportError: Could not import settings 'module.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named settings
```

When I run `django-admin.py help <some subcommands>` I get this error:

```
ImportError: Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined.
```

I'm sure somewhere I have the path to the settings set, but I can't find it. Any ideas?

Comment: If any of the following posts is solution to the problem, accept it as the answer, as it'd prove helpful for others.

Answer (score 0):

I've used these places in the past:

- You might have set the PYTHONPATH environment variable in you .bashrc / .bash_history / some other shell startup file
- You might have set said variable in your virtualenv in the `$virtualenv/bin/activate` script
- You migth have symlinked your project from within `$virtualenv/lib/pythonx.y/site-packages`

Comment: Thanks -- I checked all those places and can't find any Django settings. I ended up just reverting back to the default folder structure.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because of the following possibilities:

1. You aren't running the command from your project root i.e. `project/` , not `project/project`.
2. Have not the project root i.e. `project/` added to `PYTHONPATH`
3. Your `manage.py` isn't at project root i.e. `project/` , instead it is in `project/project`.

---

**Possible Solutions**:

1. add the project root i.e. `project/` to `PYTHONPATH` - because `manage.py` tries to do the equivalent of an `import project.settings` and for that to happen it needs to find `project` in `sys.path`
2. if you have the project root (`project/`) listed in `PYTHONPATH` - issue must be `manage.py` importing settings in form `project.settings`, where you have them both at the same level i.e. it has to be just `settings` - so move your `manage.py` one level up, to the project root, `project/` from the current `project/project`.
3. set `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` to `project.settings`.

`project.settings` indicates that the setting module is one dir lower than `manage.py` - as in your case you're having both `manage.py` and `settings.py` at the same level i.e. `project/project/`
That is you have not used the default django project structure.
Anyways you can check  /export settings just before running 'runserver' command: (from Official Django documentation - [setting `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/#envvar-DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE))

Example **(Unix Bash shell)**:

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.settings
django-admin.py runserver
```

Example **(Windows shell):**

```
set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.settings
django-admin.py runserver
```

---

**Suggestion**: Try to abide by the conventional project structure (atleast till you become an expert). i.e. keep `manage.py` one dir level up the other project files .. `settings.py`, `urls.py` , etc